# Google Map Api Return Zero Results

Tags: google-maps

I want to know why this request return zero result
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=34.1279625,74.8343285&sensor=true

It should give address components and information related to the location you can check the result of this link http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=28.5561671,77.0977691&sensor=true

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is a "disputed area":
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jammu_and_Kashmir

Reverse geocoding doesn't work in disputed areas.

See the related [Issue 8783: Bug: ZERO_RESULTS when lat & lng given](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8783) in the issue tracker